# Getting ID of a control from gridview edit mode to be used by Javascript

Tags: javascript, vb.net, gridview

hopefully someone can help me out, I've been struggling for a couple days.

Basically what needs to happen is when the user clicks edit onto the gridview and clicks on a certain textbox a javascript calendar popups up and the user picks a date.

So far, I can set it statically and the calendar works for that one row, but not the other rows since the ID changes.

My ASP Code (id of textbox has been set to txtStartDate):

```
<asp:TemplateField SortExpression="StartDate" HeaderText="Start Date">
            <EditItemTemplate>
             <asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDate" onClick="ddlchange()" Runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("StartDate")%>'> 

                </asp:TextBox>         
            </EditItemTemplate>

            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("StartDate")%>'></asp:Label>                   
            </ItemTemplate>

            </asp:TemplateField>
```

Javascript Function that contains the Calendar

```
$("#ctl00_cphMain_GridView1_ctl02_txtStartDate").datepicker({ changeMonth: true });
//getter
var changeMonth = $("#ctl00_cphMain_GridView1_ctl02_txtStartDate").datepicker("option", "changeMonth");
//setter
$("#ctl00_cphMain_GridView1_ctl02_txtStartDate").datepicker("option", "changeMonth", true);

$("#ctl00_cphMain_GridView1_ctl02_txtStartDate").datepicker({ changeYear: true });
//getter
var changeYear = $("#ctl00_cphMain_GridView1_ctl02_txtStartDate").datepicker("option", "changeYear");
//setter
$("#ctl00_cphMain_GridView1_ctl02_txtStartDate").datepicker("option", "changeYear", true);
```

This works, for one textbox. It does not work for other since 'ct102' changes with every row.

Comment: **Whoa**. Do *not* hardcode your names like that. Set the client id behavior of your controls to be constant if you need to, but do not hardcode control names rendered by ASP.NET.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why? I did that for another control where I require a dropdown list in edit mode and works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you give your TextBoxes a class and then use a class selector to assign the datepicker?

e.g.:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDate" onClick="ddlchange()" Runat="server" 
             Text='<%#Bind("StartDate")%>' CssClass="dateTextBox">

$(".dateTextBox").datepicker("option", "changeMonth", true);
```